# Visual Studio becomes unresponsive when running a program using a SoundEffect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna

I have a song and I want it to play in an XNA project. I added the song to the Content directory and changed its Content Importer to `MP3 Audio File - XNA Framework` and its Content Processor to `SoundEffect - XNA Framework`. I am using the code

```
 SoundEffectInstance music = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("music").CreateInstance()
```

But whenever I run the project Visual Studio becomes unresponsive and crashes before being able to display any output. Visual Studio doesn't crash when I change the content processor of the file to `Song - XNA Framework`, but when I do this, I receive an error while loading the file.

Why does Visual Studio keep crashing and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: `Content.Load<Texture2D>`...?

Comment: @davidsbro oops sorry that was a mistake correcting it

Comment: @davidsbro It basicaly says that I'm trying to load Song as SoundEffect

Comment: Just so you know, I think people would be more willing to help if they see that you accept answers. :) I know I'd be. But I think I might know what your problem is...one second.

Comment: Is Visual Studio actually crashing, or is it not responding?

Comment: @davidsbro the loading blue circle goes on and on (on windows 7) and when I click Visual Studio, it says not responding

Comment: It may take a long time for the song to build into an .xnb file...it took about 3 or 4 minutes to build a 3:30 song when I tried just now, so you may have to just wait. How long is your song, and how long have you tried waiting?

Comment: @davidsbro its about 5 mins long and guess I waited for like 1 or 2 minutes. If the problem is that, is there a way to bring the waiting time down?

Comment: @davidsbro And yes that was the actual problem waited a few more minutes and it gets running. Thanks for your help. And what about to reduce the not responding time?

Comment: @davidsbro I the problem is solved by itself second I build the project, it didnt unresponsive at all. Thanks one more time

Comment: Sure! The first time the file builds, XNA converts the file into an .XNB file in your Debug Directory (which can take several minutes as you know...;)). After XNA builds it the first time, it reuses that .XNB file so it won't take several minutes after the first build. Glad it helped! Would you like me to put an answer so we can delete the comments?

Comment: @davidsbro of course, would gladly accept your answer :)

Comment: When you say "run the project", you mean you press "F5", or "Ctrl-F5", or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem just has nothing to do with your code, but with waiting for the project to compile. You have the correct content importers and processors set when VS "crashes".

XNA converts all the content files to `.XNB` files before running, and then it uses those XNB files during runtime. When you add a new content item, XNA has to convert it to an XNB file once; after that, XNA reuses the XNB file everytime the game runs. It can take several minutes to convert files, especially big files (like several minute long audio files). So I would try waiting several minutes for the project to compile (if there's a wait cursor, don't get impatient with VS...just wait). Once the project builds once, you won't have to wait several minutes anymore.

Answer (score -1):

MP3 files are used for the type of `Song` if you want to use it as a sound effect then you have to make it a .WAV

Otherwise use this:

```
Song music = Content.Load<Song>("music");
MediaPlayer.Play(music);
```

Comment: -1: you should read the comments on the question - you'll realize the question has nothing to do with this.